# C - Linked lists: free() function is deleting my head node; how do I use free() correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I need to make a function that drops the first n nodes of a linked list in c and returns the number of removed nodes. If the list is smaller than n, it should become empty. *Also, I cannot use recursvity.*

With the code as it is right now, it works but I am not freeing the memory of the "deleted" nodes. If I uncomment the part that should free the memory, I get this error on codeboard.io:

```
Input: 5 + [ 61 62 63 64 65 66 ]
Output: expected 5 + [ 66 ]
        obtained 5 + [19333664 ]
```

That random number seems to be that it is accessing "junk" in memory.
How do I correctly free the nodes I don't use anymore?

**Code inside listas.h:**

```
typedef struct lligada {
    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;

LInt newLInt (int, LInt);

int drop (int, LInt *);
```

**Code inside listas.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "listas.h"

int drop (int n, LInt *l){
    int count = 0;
    LInt *aux;
    while(n>0 && (*l)!=NULL){
          n--;
          count++;
          //aux = &((*l));
          *l = (*l)->prox;
          //free(*aux);
    }
return count;
}
```

Codeboard link to exercise: https://codeboard.io/projects/16259

Comment: I overlooked the fact that `l` is a double pointer when writing my answer. Sorry for that. In general it is recommended to use normal pointers instead of multi-level pointers.

Comment: Ok, got it. I think I understand it now!

Comment: strongly suggest:  do not hide a 'pointer' via a 'typedef'.  Rather use the typedef to give the struct a 'short' name, then when declaring an instance of the struct, make it a pointer.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: variable names should be meaningful, ('l' and 'n' are not meaningful) A variable name should indicate content or usage (or better, both).

Comment: inside the `drop()` function this line: `LInt *aux;` should have caused the compiler to output a warning message.  Because the variable `aux` is neither set nor used.   When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `LInt` it defined to be a *pointer* to `struct lligada`. Therefore, the `l` parameter to the `drop` function is a *pointer to a pointer* to `struct lligada`. Let's call the `LInt` variable that `l` points to `list_head`.

So, the line:

```
aux = &((*l));
```

Is actually assigning to `aux` the address of `list_head` and not the `struct lligada` that `list_head` points to.

Thus, the solution will be to define `aux` as `LInt` and then do:

```
aux = *l;
*l = (*l)->prox;
free(aux);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I reached a similar solution to that of jboockmann by not making aux a double pointer, but as I said under his solution I don't understand what and why that was wrong.

```
int drop (int n, LInt *l){
    int count = 0;
    LInt aux;
    while(n>0 && (*l)!=NULL){
          n--;
          count++;
          aux = *l;
          *l = (*l)->prox;
          free(aux);
        }
    return count;
}
```